# Why does org.json.JSONObject.sortedKeys() is removed in new version of org.json.JSONObect jar?

Tags: java, json

Previously i used older versions of json jar but now upgraded to new jar(json-20230618.jar).
In this new jar I am not able to find sortedKeys() method.
How to achieve sorted order in new jar?

Comment: Just get the keys and sort them by yourself

Comment: It's easy, convert your JSON object to a `Map`,then sort the keys of the `Map` using any sorting algorithm of your choice, and iterate over the sorted keys and retrieve the corresponding values from the `Map`!